# How to implement SSL on AWS instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-ec2, elastic-load-balancer

I have 2 websites hosted on `AWS EC2`. I created a single instance and hosted both sites there. I have deployed the SSL for one site by creating the `ELB` for that. 
How can I deploy the SSL on the other site using `ACM` on the same instance?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a single Application Load Balancer for both sites on the same server (or even multiple servers) by configuring your HTTPS listener rules to forward the traffic to specific target group according to the host name.

You won't need to install any SSL certificate on the server itself. The ELB communicates with the server over TCP/IP port 80. You'll need to add a HTTP-to-HTTPS redirect rules in your Web server of course if you don't want to allow insecure connections.

See [Listener Rules for Your Application Load Balancer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/listener-update-rules.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can simply create a second ELB and assign your second wildcard certificate to it. You can also forward your traffic to the same backend server as the one where the first ELB is forwarding its traffic to.

In this scenario you can do the following:

1. Create a new ELB
2. Create appropriate listeners on your new ELB
3. Point your second domain to your new ELB (using cname record)
4. Register your existing instances with your new ELB

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have both sites on same instance and I have already created an `ELB` for the site A (where SSL is deployed). Do I need to create another `ELB` for the same instance?

Comment: Yes that is not the issue hope you have mapped nginx or apache appropriately ? If it is nginx use https://garthkerr.com/multiple-ssl-domains-on-elb-with-nginx/

Comment: Yes I have created the vhosts properly. I am using `Apache`

Comment: Also Update the answer , Refer https://web.archive.org/web/20130914191613/http://elwoodicious.com/2009/12/23/using-elb-to-serve-multiple-domains-over-ssl-on-ec2-for-giggles/